# add plus 1increment if text contains

Tags: excel

I have the following dates

```
18/04/2019
19/04/2019
20/04/2019
21/04/2019
22/04/2019
```

I am creating a calendar to mark whether the date is a weekend or workday. I used the following formula  =IF(WEEKDAY(D3,2)>5,"WEEKEND","WORKDAY " & COUNTA($B$3:B3))

This returns:

```
WORKDAY 1   18/04/2019
WORKDAY 2   19/04/2019
WEEKEND         20/04/2019
WEEKEND         21/04/2019
WORKDAY 5   22/04/2019
```

I would like it to return every time it is a workday to add the next number next to it

so

```
WORKDAY 1   18/04/2019
WORKDAY 2   19/04/2019
WEEKEND         20/04/2019
WEEKEND         21/04/2019
WORKDAY 3   22/04/2019
```

how would I alter my formula to do this

Comment: This would be rather simple to do with VBA in Excel. You'd just loop, and fill numbers only for weekdays and keep cells empty for weekends.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your calendar includes a single instance of all dates (or, at least, all work dates):

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(D3)>5,"WEEKEND","WORKDAY " & NETWORKDAYS($D$3,D3))
```

[image]